How to examine whether ERESOURCE is null before deleting it?
When I want to create a C++ RAII wrappers for executive resources,I've come across this issue.
#include <ntddk.h>

class ExecutiveResource
{
public:
    ExecutiveResource()
    {
        ExInitializeResource(&resource);
    }

    ~ExecutiveResource()
    {
        if (resource)    //How I do the examination?
        {
            ExDeleteResourceLite(&resource);
        }

    }

    ExecutiveResource(const ExecutiveResource&) = delete;
    ExecutiveResource& operator=(const ExecutiveResource&) = delete;

    ExecutiveResource(ExecutiveResource&& other)    noexcept
    {
        resource = other.resource;
        other.resource = {};
    }

    ExecutiveResource& operator=(ExecutiveResource&& other) noexcept {
        if (this != &other) {
            ExDeleteResourceLite(&resource);
            resource = other.resource;
            other.resource = {};
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void AcquireExclusive()
    {
        ExEnterCriticalRegionAndAcquireResourceExclusive(&resource);
    }

    void AcquireShared()
    {
        ExEnterCriticalRegionAndAcquireResourceShared(&resource);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        ExReleaseResourceAndLeaveCriticalRegion(&resource);
    }

private:
    ERESOURCE resource{};
};

If the object is a pointer,I just need to compare it with nullptr.ERESOURCE can't be coverted to bool type,how I do the examination?

You have an ERESOURCE as a member, so it is always there. There is no "null", just there is no null int. But before you even get there, you should have noticed that you are copying an ERESOURCE, and those objects are clearly not copyable. (I mean what would it mean to copy an ERESOURCE that somebody is waiting for?)

@RaymondChen Thanks for your comment, I did make a conceptual mistake indeed, but I'm still a bit confused about what you referred to as 'copying an ERESOURCE.' Are you referring to the code in the move constructor and move assignment? In those codes, I do perform a copy operation, but then I assign an empty initializer list to the previous ERESOURCE. My intention is simply to perform a move operation to ensure that ERESOURCE is exclusive. Have I made any mistakes here? Looking forward to your reply.

An ERESOURCE is an opaque type. Opaque means that you cannot access its contents. The only supported operations are those provided by the resource APIs. Memberwise copying and memberwise zeroing are both illegal member accesses.

@RaymondChen OK,your comment is so useful for me.So I'm supposed to remove the move constructor and move assignment.And I dont' need to examine resource in the deconstructor.Is it right?
